# How can I normalize two histograms in OpenCV?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I'm working on a CBIR image processing project and I need to normalize two histograms such that their values are on the same scale.  I'm not quite sure if normalizing is the right term for it though.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am slicing each image (single channel grayscale) into an 8x8 grid.  Therefore, for some images the blocks of the grid may be larger and for others smaller.  But for each block, I'm extracting a 256 bin histogram as a feature for storage and comparison against other features later, ergo all images have equal sized feature descriptors, regardless of size differences.

As it stands, this doesn't scale properly, as images with larger blocks have higher counts in each bin, but could simply be a 2x scale of the same image.

It's because of this I want to store histograms such that each bin value is the percentage of their occurrence over a 2D region in the grid.  Doing so, I would able to compare histograms with both according to the same scale.

Can I accomplish this using OpenCV?  I'm not sure if it's a common practice and I'm just not aware of the nomenclature.

Comment: So why not simply divide each bin by the total number of pixels in the block?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that too, but I was hoping there would be an efficient implementation in OpenCV to accomplish this.  I'm also curious as to whether or not there is actually common practice when it comes to supporting histogram comparison.

Comment: With OpenCV, comparing histograms is normally done with [compareHist](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) so I guess it boils down to the reason why you're comparing them.

Comment: Well my end goal is to parallelize a histogram difference implementation myself, effectively by copying multiple histograms into CIImages in iOS and pass them to a custom filter kernel which will simply output the sum of absolute differences across two images (which it will do in parallel in GPU).  I don't think cv::calculateHist can do this as efficiently as necessary, because my program will need to do this an outrageous amount of times, so I need to crush as much work together as possible.

Comment: Ok, your call, just beware of [premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). It's better to get the algorithm right, then profile, then optimise if necessary. Don't be tempted to guess that something will be "too slow" without measuring it.